# Retrieving entities in JPQL, EclipseLink and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, eclipselink, jpql

I've persisted some Book entities in a database called Books created by MySQL.
This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="mysqltest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

<!-- list all classes -->
<class>it.mysql.beginner.User</class>
<class>it.mysql.beginner.Book</class>
<class>it.mysql.beginner.Kind</class>

<properties>
  <!-- some properties needed by persistence provider:
    - driver
    - db url
    - db user name
    - db user password -->
  <property name="javax.persistence.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Books"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="lory"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="brookhaven12#"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />

  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />

  </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

this is a generic jpaDAO

```
public abstract class jpaDAO<E> {

protected Class<E> entityClass;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "mysqltest")
protected EntityManager em;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public jpaDAO() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public List<E> findAll() {
    TypedQuery<E> q = em.createQuery("SELECT h FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " h", entityClass);
    return q.getResultList();
}
...
```

and this is a BookDAO:

```
public class BookDAO extends jpaDAO<Book> {

public List<Book> findByAuthor(String author) {

    List<Book> bookList;

    TypedQuery<Book> query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.author = author", entityClass);

            query.setParameter("author", author);

            bookList = query.getResultList();

    return bookList;

}
}
```

In the main program I perform:

```
List<Book> allBooks;
BookDAO bookDAO = new BookDAO();

allBooks = bookDAO.findByAuthor("Stephen King");
```

and then both bookDao.findAll() and bookDao.findByAuthor("author") but I get
NullPointerException so I imagine that the list allBooks is empty.
I don't understand...there are books stored in the database, why doesn't it get them?

Comment: Why the hell are you catching a NullPointerException? A NullPointerException is a bug. Catching it will hide the bug, not solve it. Don't catch NullPointerException. Never return null from a method returning a collection. And fix your query and your method: it doesn't use the author argument.

Comment: I've written the corrections you've said but, even if I don't catch Exception, this is what I read from the console:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at it.mysql.beginner.dao.BookDAO.findByAuthor(BookDAO.java:20)
 at it.mysql.beginner.Main.main(Main.java:138)

Comment: It seems that I get this NullPointerException when I perform this:

Comment: TypedQuery<Book> query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.author = author", entityClass);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `new BookDAO()`. But neither the BookDAO constructor, not the superclass constructor, initializes the `em` field. So it is null. So when you call a method on `em`, you get a NullPointerException.

The EntityManager is supposed to be injected by the container (you've not specified if you ran inside an EJB/CDI container, or if you were using Spring). But that is only possible if you get a BookDAO instance from the container. If you instanciate it yourself, the container doesn't know anything about this object, and thus can't inject any field of this object.

So, your BookDAO should be injected into its caller (which should itself be instanciated by the container).

It's impossible to give more details without knowing what the caller is, and in which environment you're running.

Comment: I'm trying to using Spring...Should I use an @Autowired bookDAO? I'm really new to all these things and I'm havening a lot of confusion...

Comment: Yes, you should use an Autowired BookDAO. Everything that must be injected must come from the Spring container.

Comment: I get the same error...I'm really in panic, would you be so kind to write some code for me?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. Being in pani won't help. Take some time to read the Spring documentation and grasp the concept of dependency injection. It's crucial.

Comment: For the moment I've solved the problem by adding in a explicit way what was missing:

Comment: protected EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysqltest");
 protected EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();